# Maven: output all Java classes or packages being built into a separate file

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I need Maven to output (log) all Java classes or packages being built into some separate text file, let say, something like AllClasses.txt that will contain in the end:

```
my.app.Hello
my.app.Main
my.app.Utils
...
```

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: looks more like a task for the command prompt (dir) or a unix command

Comment: Or an ANT task invoked through the antrun maven plugin that loops over the generated classes in the target folder or something...

Comment: @EJP We need this list for the fine logger configuration. Javaagents and WAR/EAR/JAR parsing during a runtime are not wanted due to some restrictions which are not interesting here.

Comment: They're interesting to me. That's why I asked, oddly enough. It seems to me that you don't trust that the result of a Maven build will be built versions of everything that needs building. And this is build-time, not run-time. Please clarify.

Comment: Java Classes being built or built & packaged as well ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no readily available plugin for that. You have to extend maven compile plug-in for that.
We did similar thing for a project in past.